# How to compare date in if statement for style attribute in apex:column

Tags: apex, visualforce

i am trying to collor rows in an apex:column according to a date condition,

i am missing something in the syntax,

i am getting this error: " Syntax error.  Missing ')' "

can't find the problem..

here is my code:

```
<apex:page controller="FlightsListController" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Flights Gant" id="flights_gant">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! flights}" var="flight"> 
           <apex:column value="{! flight.Time_of_Arrival}"  
                         style="{!IF( flight.Time_of_Arrival==Date(2017,10,25 04:04), 'background-color:blue;',
                                    'background-color:green;')}"/>       
            <apex:column value="{! flight.Flight_Number__c }" />
            <apex:column value="{! flight.Suitcases__c }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>      
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **datetime** value in **Date** format `Date(2017,10,2504:04)` 
Please use this `DATETIMEVALUE('2017-10-25 06:40:00')`
Hope it will help you.

Comment: so now the syntax is ok but the color didn't change. any idea why?  see link: https://img42.com/3xooA

Comment: Please check your exact time via SOQL query and add them. it's also happen with me.

Comment: 2017-10-31T20:50:00.000Z - this is the format returned from my query, so what is my mistake in the syntax?

Comment: DATETIMEVALUE('2017-10-31 20:50:00') add this, hope it will success

Comment: it works with this date but not with other dates. weird.

Comment: It is based on time. who's record comes in this time that's works.. OR if you use Date then record of that date will work.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the difference between: DATETIMEVALUE('2017-10-31 20:50:00') that works and: DATETIMEVALUE('2017-10-25 14:45:00') that doesn't work?

Comment: DATETIMEVALUE('2017-10-25 14:45:00') maybe this format of record is not available. Please check once.